# using one line if in linq statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have multiple drop-down lists with default value of 0 which indicates that user not selected any option and other numbers with mean user selected an value and it should include in LINQ query. My problem is I can not check if the user selected any options in drop-down lists or not?

This is my try for first drop-down list:

```
var ddl1 = Convert.ToInt32(ddlDastgAhasli.SelectedValue);


var project = (from p in context.Projects 
               where Convert.ToInt32(p.DastgahEjraeiAsli) == ((ddl1 == 0) ? null : ddl1) select p);
```

This is the error:

> type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversation '' and 'int'

Comment: it is asp.net im using

Comment: Looks like there's one `Project` where `p.DastgahEjraeiAsli` is an empty string and can't be converted to an integer, however I can't quite see how your exact example would compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved by putting "Convert.ToInt32(p.DastgahEjraeiAsli)" instead of null, so if the ddl1 == 0 (user hasn't selected any item) where skips.

```
var project = (from p in context.Projects 
           where Convert.ToInt32(p.DastgahEjraeiAsli) == ((ddl1 == 0) ? Convert.ToInt32(p.DastgahEjraeiAsli) : ddl1) select p);
```

this is very useful when for example u have a search form with multiple texboxs and dropdownlists and user may choose each of them and you do not know which one will be selected and which one not.

simplified example :

in the search button click event:

```
int ddl1 = Convert.ToInt32(dropdownlist1.selectedvalue);
int ddl2 = Convert.ToInt32(dropdownlist2.selectedvalue);
string txt1 = textbox1.text;


var project = (from p in context.mytable
                       where p.field1 == ((ddl1 == 0) ? p.field1 : ddl1)
                                   && p.field2 == ((ddl2 == 0) ? p.field2 : ddl2)
                                   && p.field3 == ((txt1 == "") ? p.field3 : txt1)

                       select p).ToList();


gridview1.datasource = project;
fridview1.databind();
```

not: each dropdownlist has a default value with text="select an item" and value="0", so if user didn't select any option default value remains 0.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems here:

1. You cant compare a value type(in your case int) to null.
2. You need to select something.

This is the structure for the query:

```
var project = (from p in context.Projects where p.prop == 1 select p);
```

And this to parse the int:

**Bad**

```
string strInt = "7";    
if(Convert.ToInt32(strInt) == null) //  compilation error
```

**Good**

```
string strInt = "7";   
int intVal;
if(int.TryParse(strInt, out intVal))
{
   // intVal is an integer
}
else
{
  // intVal isnt an integer
}
```

Comment: my goal is if (ddl1 == 0) skip the where.

Comment: You can simply if\else this. Where is your problem?

Comment: by replacing a int number with null in the linq query error goes away but I don't want to compare  "Convert.ToInt32(p.DastgahEjraeiAsli)" with that number I want if (ddl1 == 0) skip the where that's why I Used null. can u provide an example show how to do this?

Comment: Do it with an if\else. It will take 2 more lines of code but your code will be easy to read\debug\understand. Placing "null" and "disabling the where" isn't really the right thing to do..

If you insist of doing that, use a nullable int(can be null or int).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to skip the `where` condition when `ddl1` isn't set, you can just conditionally add the `where` clause when actually needed, something like (with the somewhat silly example of all ddls comparing to the same field)

```
var project = (from p in context.Projects select p);

if(ddl1 != 0)
{
    project = project.Where(Convert.ToInt32(p.DastgahEjraeiAsli) == ddl1);
}

if(ddl2 != 0)
{
    project = project.Where(Convert.ToInt32(p.DastgahEjraeiAsli) == ddl2);
}

...
```

This will effectively require all where clauses where `ddlx != 0` to be true, and the ones where the ddl is 0 are not in any way affecting the query.

Comment: Yes, but this will work if there is only one ddl but in this scenario there are many of them which user may select one or more of them. for example ddl2,ddl3, ... and

Comment: @farhang67 There's nothing preventing you from adding more than one condition dynamically, I'll update the answer.

Comment: it should return query result in one object but using this snippet doesn't serve that

Comment: @farhang67 I'm not sure what you mean by "one object", both your original question and this query build an `IQueryable<Project>` which you can evaluate, for example using `ToArray()` to get the matching results.

Comment: The problem here is that user may select ddl1 and ddl3 but not ddl2 in that case linq query should be somthing like this : from p in mycontext.mytable where ddl1 == p.myrecord && ddl3 == p.myrecord2. We Do not know what will be user choices there are lots of possibilities and in your way lots of if statements are needed.

Comment: @farhang67 You need one statement per "ddl", and once you're done a single query is passed to the database. To me it would seem like adding an extra `if` statement per `ddl` would be easier than trying to add it to a complex condition with all of them at once.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very useful extension method which i use in my projects to solve various checks..Its not about only ASP.NET..You can use it in winforms etc. also

```
    public IEnumerable<Control> GetAll(Control control)
     {        
       var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();

       return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAll(ctrl))
       .Concat(controls)
       .Where(c => c.Visible == true);
//If you don't need to check that the control's visibility then simply ignore the where clause..

     }
```

with this method no matter your control (in your situation dropdownlists) is a member/child of another control under that control which the control you pass as parameter to the method..Method checks recursively started from given parameter and checks all child controls related to given control as Method parameter..

And Usage in code :

```
    //Its Assumed you need to check DropDownList' SelectedIndex property

      List<Control> dropDownsOfPageWhichTheirSelectedIndexIsZero
                            = new List<Control>( GetAll ( YourAspNetPage )
                              .Where( x => x is DropDownList 
                              && ( ( DropDownList ) x ) . SelectedIndex == 0 ) ) ;

// Lets check if our page has dropdowns which their SelectedIndex equals to Zero
if ( dropDownsOfPageWhichTheirSelectedIndexIsZero . Count > 0 )
{
  // do your work what you need in your project
  //suppose you need their names and do something with this name (i.e.warn a message to user)

    foreach ( DropDownList ddl in dropDownsOfPageWhichTheirSelectedIndexIsZero )
    {
      alert ("Please Check "+ ddl.Name +".Should Chost other than \"Select\" option");
    }
}
```

Hope this Helps..